# Blob video to File js => empty

Tags: javascript, php, blob, vimeo-api

I'm currently creating a web site where users can upload videos, captured with webRTC/mediarecorder. Resulting in a blob video, ( working I can watch or download ) I try to make a js file from it, the purpose is to send it to the server, who's sending to vimeo API.

Like that : `new File([myBlob], "uploaded_video.mp4", {type: "video/mpeg", lastModified: Date.now()});`

No error, but resulting in an empty file ( with a name and date but with a size of 63o )

I've already tested with some different type/format of blob, same result

Any idea or someone knows the case?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is myBlob.size?

Comment: Hum, it depend, it comes from a stream